# How to check whether cart is mine or other shop using Amazon SP-API productsPricing

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I would like to know which attibute specifies the cart is mine or other shop.

This is becasue there are too many attibutes that we could get and it dose not state clearly which one is which.

I am refering following.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/c3d661d155db59c62b923402e8ee2c6650b73442/references/product-pricing-api/productPricingV0.md#getcompetitivepricing

Best regards,

I went through all the attributes, but, I cannot find myself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Keep in mind to trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like Amazon indicates whether your item is the item with the best price. You can use the `getCompetitivePricing()` call to get a list of prices that compete for a given list of ASINs. See documentation here:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-pricing-api-v0-use-case-guide
There is also a newer api that has a `getFeaturedOfferExpectedPriceBatch()` call to get the price that a seller can use to become the featured offer, perhaps that is what you are looking for. https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-pricing-api-v2022-05-01-reference